# How to call a .exe file in C#

Tags: c#, .net

My Requirement is i need to call an .exe file through C# Program

Can anyone please help me out on how to call an .exe file in C# Programming with a syntax ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Process.Start("path to your .exe")`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ExeFilePath);  
   //start the app according to the path provided
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to open, for example, microsoft word passing a parameter to open a file in this case

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
    startInfo.Arguments = "c:/yourfile.doc";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```